# Conditional Display Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display a delete button only if the current user is the "host" but the button is hidden even if the user id for the host matches the user id for the guest

```
<%= link_to "X" , "/songs?name=#{s.name}&party_profile_id=#{s.party_profile_id}&commit=X", :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-small refreshbutton", :style => "display:none" unless @current_user.id == @party_profile.host %>
```

Am I using the wrong syntax? Is there a better way to conditionally display items?

Comment: Is `@party_profile.host` an integer, because `@current_user.id` almost certainly is, and I wonder if they can ever be the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could switch to only render it, rather than toggling the css class (unless your application would need to toggle it client side for some reason).

```
<% if @current_user.id == @party_profile.host %>
    <%= link_to "X" , "/songs?name=#{s.name}&party_profile_id=#{s.party_profile_id}&commit=X", :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your condition would apply to the link itself, not the `style` attribute.

Do this instead:

```
<%= link_to "X" , "/songs?name=#{s.name}&party_profile_id=#{s.party_profile_id}&commit=X", :remote => true, :class => "btn btn-inverse btn-small refreshbutton", :style => "#{'display:none;' unless @current_user.id == @party_profile.host}"  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be

`if @current_user.id == @party_profile.host` ?

Edit:

you don't need to set the style to display none.  The if statement will handle whether it is rendered in the view.

Comment: No. He's trying to set the style to 'display:none' in those cases.